# linq exression returning value

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm trying to use a linq expression in order to get certain properties associated with job orders that are related to those records. I'm having an issue actually accessing the values.

```
var accountManagerObject = (
    from j in api.hc_joborderSet
    where j.statecode == hc_joborderState.Active &&
        j.hc_systemuser_hc_joborder_AccountManager != null &&
        j.hc_ExpirationDate <= dateFilter
    select new { accountmangerid = j.hc_AccountManager.Id, jobid = j.Id, jobName = j.LogicalName })
    .ToLookup(o=>o.accountmangerid);

foreach (var jobId in accountManagerObject.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(jobId.Select(o=>o.jobName));
}
```

Instead of returning values my writeline is returning

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.String],System.String]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.String],System.String]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.String],System.String]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.String],System.String]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.Guid,System.Guid,System.String],System.String]

Comment: Why are you calling .ToLookup().ToList()?  Did you really want both these datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Select()` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. And this instance's `ToString()` method only gives you the type name.

You probably wanted to display the sequence of `jobName`s. This can for example be done like that:

```
foreach (var jobId in accountManagerObject)
{
    foreach(string jobName in jobId.Select(o=>o.jobName))
        Console.WriteLine(jobName);
}
```

or shorter using `string.Join`:

```
foreach (var jobId in accountManagerObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, jobId.Select(o=>o.jobName)));    
}
```

Note that the `.ToList()` call in your `foreach` is unnecessary and should be ommitted. There is no need to create a new list from this `LookUp` just to iterate through.